# aws backups snapshot not moving to cold storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

I had set up an AWS backup plan which takes backup of our EC2 instances and EBS volumes. But for some reason it is not moving it to cold storage

Here is my backup plan:

Frequency
Daily
At 05:00 AM UTC

Start within
8 hours

Complete within
7 days

Lifecycle
Transition to cold storage after 2 days

Expire after 95 days

For some reason, it is not moving to cold storage
[image: Backup vault]
[image: Backup vault]

Not sure what I am missing
Any help is much appriciated

EDIT: So i have noticed that the backups are been removed from the vault(moved to cold storage) after 9 days. But I have mentioned in the backup plan to move it to cold storage in 2 days. I assume it takes 9 days because completewithin(7 days) + 2 days. Is this the case?

Comment: sorry but based on this image, how should I know if it is not working? Should it say 'cold storage` somewhere? have you check you S3 bucket?

Comment: @brushtakopo The transition to cold storage column is Never. Sorry should have included that in the screenshot earlier

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe transition to cold storage is supported for ec2/ebs - checkout the matrix (and the faq):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/whatisbackup.html#features-by-resource

Comment: this is link only answer